# How to create a group of routes in Silex/Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, routes, silex

in Slim PHP you can create a group of route and a mapping for one route following this way:

```
$app->group('/firstRoute', function () {
  $this->map(['GET', 'POST'], '/secondRoute', 'Controller:functionA')->setName('X');
  $this->map(['GET', 'POST'], '/thirdRoute', 'Controller:functionB')->setName('Y');
}
```

But I don't know how to do the same in Silex/Symfony

1. Is it possible to create a kind of group like this in Silex ?
2. Then how to map (different HTTP methods in one route) ?

Thanks guys

Comment: My bad thank you Momin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can map different http method by calling `match` function as shown below:

```
$app->match('/blog', function () {
   // ...
});
```

Comment: And you can even fine tune that by calling the [```->method``` method](https://github.com/silexphp/Silex/blob/master/src/Silex/Route.php#L112) (for example ```$app->match('/blog', function() { ... })->method('GET|POST')```

Comment: Thank you dude !!